# Is there a pure geometric solution to this problem?

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a square and there is a point $E$ such that $\angle EAB = 15^{\circ}$ and $\angle EBA = 15^{\circ}$. Show that $\triangle EDC$ is an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Now there is a proof by contradiction to this problem. I was wondering if there is a pure geometric solution too (no trigonometry)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a geometric solution provided by Dr.Shailesh Shirali:

Draw a copy of triangle EAB with DA as base. That is, locate point F inside the square such that triangle FDA is congruent to triangle EAB.

Then angle FAD = angle EAB = 15 deg, so angle FAE = 60 deg. Also, FA = EA. Hence triangle FAE is equilateral, and angle AFE = 60 deg, and FA = FD = FE.

Therefore F is equidistant from A, D, E and so is the circumcentre of triangle DAE.

Therefore by the circle theorems, angle AFE = 2 angle ADE.

But angle AFE = 60 deg. Hence angle ADE = 30 deg, and it follows that angle CDE = 60 deg. So triangle CDE is equilateral.

[image]

Comment: Great solution. It's easy to follow every step. But, as always with such "tricks": how can one come up with such a solution not knowing the simple solution upfront? What was the train of thoughts / strategy which one could follow to actually come up with such a solution themselves?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to show that $\triangle CDE$ is equilateral is to construct an equilateral triangle $\triangle CDE'$ and argue that $\angle ABE'=\angle BAE'=15^\circ$. One can easily see this by looking at the isosceles triangles $\triangle ADE'$ and $\triangle BCE'$.

It is then obvious that $E$ coincides with $E'$.

---

Here's another proof which is not "backward":

[image]

Construct $F$ such that $\angle BCF=\angle BCF=15^\circ$. It follows that $\triangle BEF$ is equilateral since $BE=BF$ and $\angle EBF=60^\circ$.

Also $CF\perp EB$ as $\angle FCB+\angle EBC=90^\circ$. That means the line $CF$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BE$. Thus $CE=CD$.

Comment: You mean, line $CF$ is the perpendicular bisector of line segment $BE$? (I'm not sure how you got that. I get the "perpendicular" part, though.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Note that I already showed $\triangle BEF$ is equilateral, that mean $F$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $BE$ already. And thanks for spotting out the typo.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, $CE=CB$ because $C$ is on the perpendicular bisector, and $CB=CD$ because it's a square... and this leads to $CE=CD$, as claimed. (And, by symmetry, $CE=DE$, and we have $CD=CE=DE$ so $\triangle CDE$ is equilateral.)

Answer (score 1):

Reflect triangle $AED$ in $AE$ to obtain $AED'$.  Then $\angle BAD'$ is $60^{\circ}$.  Since $AB=AD=AD'$ this implies that $D'$ is straight below $E$ and therefore $\angle AED=\angle AED'=75^{\circ}$.  Then $\angle CDE=75^{\circ}-15^{\circ}=60^{\circ}$.

Comment: Nice! (+1) ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Pirsquare

Let $DC=a~$ and $EC=b$. Using cosine and sine theorems in triangles $EDC$ and $EBC$
, respectively we get that,$~a=2bcosx~$and $~\frac{sin(15+x)}{a}=\frac{sin75}{b}~$.These equations yield $\frac{sin(15+x)}{cosx}=2cos15~$. Finally, $tanx=2-tan15=\sqrt3$. So, $x=60~$.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a solution without involving trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you mean by "proof by contradiction", anyway:

Don't assume you know the angles $EAB$ and $EBA$, but assume instead that the triangle $DCE$ is equilateral.

Then triangles $DEA, CEB$ are isoscele, thus $CEB=CBE=DEA=DAE$. But $EDA=ECB=90°-60°=30°$. Thus $DAE=CBE=75°$. Then $EAB=EBA=15°$.

Since there is only one position of $E$ on the mediatrix of $DC$ such that angle $BEA$ takes on a given value, your proposition is proved.

Comment: Proof by contradiction I meant: let angle EDC =x, angle DEC=(180-2x), angle EDA=(90-x), angle DEA=(x+15).             Now suppose that x >60. Then 3x>180 therefore x>(180-2x).   Therefore angle DCE>angle DEC. Therefore DE>DC.            Also, x+15>75, so in triangle DEA we have angle DEA>angle DAE. Therefore AD>DE. Thus we have AD>DE>DC, an absurdity because AD=DC! Likewise for x<60.  So the only option left is to conclude x=60 and this means triangle DEC is equilateral.

Comment: @pirsquare So that' yet another proof. They follow the same idea: use angles to find the solution, but whereas you start from your hypothesis to find a contradiction if $x\neq60°$, I strart with an equilateral triangle to prove $BEA=15°$.