# $ABCD$ is a square and $AEB$ is an equilateral triangle. Find $\angle DEC$.

Tags: geometry

I found this question in an exam question paper. 
But I was stumped by it. It seemed that all the answers were correct. 
I tried: 
[image] 
Let $\angle ADE=x$ and $\angle EDC=y$. 
 $\angle DAB=90^{\circ}=\angle DAE+\angle EAB=30^{\circ}+60^{\circ}$.
 $\text{ref}\angle AEB=300^{\circ}$.
 And we know that $x+y=90^{\circ}$ 
But now I am stuck. How to proceed?

Comment: Explain the downvote, downvoter.

Comment: See the edit, retract the downvote please.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907837/is-there-a-pure-geometric-solution-to-this-problem

Comment: Please dont mark duplicate. It **is** indeed different.

Comment: We have $x = \frac{180^\circ-30^\circ}{2} = 75^\circ$. So, $y = 15^\circ$. Then, $\angle DEC = 150^\circ$.

Comment: Or, we have $x = 75^\circ$, then $\angle DEC = 360^\circ - 60^\circ - 2\times 75^\circ = 150^\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\triangle AEB$ is equilateral, so $|AE|=|AB|=|AD|$. Hence $\triangle DAE$ is isosceles, so $\angle ADE = \angle AED$, and so $\angle ADE = \frac{1}{2}(\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}) = 5\pi/12$.

The same procedure works on the other side of the square, and hence $\angle DEC = 2\pi-\pi/3-2 \times 5\pi/12 = 5\pi/6 = 150˚ $

Comment: Ohh! I forgot that $BE=BC$!!

Answer (score 0):

$DAE$ & $CEB$ are triangles having $BC=BE$ & $AD=AE$ now you can find $x$ ($=75^\circ$) and the others are easy.