# E is a point inside square $ABCD$ such that $ECD = EDC = 15$...

Tags: geometry

E is a point inside square ABCD such that $\angle{ECD} = \angle{EDC} = 15.$ Find $\angle{AEB}.$

I drew a picture for this but I don't know how to continue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$ABCD$ is a square and $AEB$ is an equilateral triangle. Find $\angle DEC$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434534/abcd-is-a-square-and-aeb-is-an-equilateral-triangle-find-angle-dec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct point $F$ in the interior of the square such that $\angle{FDA}=\angle{FAD}=15^{\circ}$.

$\textbf{Claim}$ $F$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle DEA$

To see this, observe that $FD=DE$ and that $\angle{FDE}=60^{\circ}$ by construction. This implies that $\triangle FDE$ is equilateral, from which the claim immediately follows.

A straightforward angle chase tells us that $\angle{FAE}=15^{\circ}$ and hence $\angle{EAB}=60^{\circ}$. We also have $EA=EB$ due to symmetry, and hence it follows that $\triangle EAB$ is equilateral. It immediately follows that $\angle EAB=60^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let the side of the square be $a$. Now, applying Sine Rule in $\triangle EFD$, we get, $$DE=\frac{a}{2\sin 75°}.$$

Now, apply Sine Rule in $\triangle DEA$ $$\frac{\sin (15°+\theta)}{\cos \theta}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}}{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Clearly, $\theta=60°$ satisfies the equation. Now, you can find $\angle AEB$.